# PHP mail() attachment filename is shown as "untitle"

Tags: php

I am trying to send email with attachment using PHP mail() function. The email gets delivered but in web mail filename appears as "untitle". With Outlook Avast heuristic blocks email completely.

Please  guide me to overcome this issue.

Here is code that I am using

```
 $recieverAdd = 'r@gamil.com';
 $subject = 'Attachment';
 $attDescription="emailing lessons";
 $filename ='example.pdf';
 $file = '/home/user/example.pdf';
 $file_size = filesize($file);
 $handle = fopen($file, "r");
 $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
 fclose($handle);
 $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
 $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
 $name = basename($file);

 $from_name = $uname;
 $from_mail = 'admin@gmail.com';
 $replyto  ='noreply@gmail.com';
 $header = "From: $from_name";      
 $header .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
     "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
     " boundary=\"{$uid}\"";

 $message = "<p><b>Hello </b></p>";
 $messageBody =  "--{$uid}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1              \"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
 $messageBody .= "--{$uid}\n". "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n".
        "name=\"{$filename1}\"\n".
        "Content-Description: {$filename}\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n".
        "filename=\"{$filename}\"; size={$file_size};\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n". $content."\n\n". "--{$uid}--\n";

 mail($recieverAdd,$subject,$messageBody,$header)
```

Comment: What is `$filename1` doing in name ?

Comment: It is typo. Actually it is $filename in code

Comment: seriously, all this messing around with the arcane mail header syntax is unnecessary. Just use a better mail class instead of php's built-in mail() function. I recommend using [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead. It's so much easier to use, and so much less fraught with problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n".
"name=\"{$filename1}\"\n".

"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n".
"filename=\"{$filename}\"; size={$file_size};\n" .
```

The `name=...` and `filename=...` parts of these headers are considered separate (invalid) header lines, because you're outputting a newline after `Content-Type: application/octet-stream;` and `Content-Disposition: attachment;`, but no whitespace after those newlines. In order to split a header into multiple lines, each continuation line must start with whitespace.

Comment: Thank lanzz and others for quik reply. It was great help. I was banging my head with this piece of code whole day.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help to you.,

Please find the below example :

```
<?php    

    $my_file = "somefile.zip";
    $my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_path_here/";
    $my_name = "Olaf Lederer";
    $my_mail = "my@mail.com";
    $my_replyto = "my_reply_to@mail.net";
    $my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
    $my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo you like this script? I hope it will help.\r\n\r\ngr. Olaf";
    mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);

?>

<?php
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
?>
```